# Space character inside an argument (emacs lisp)

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In windows, I set the variable `inferior-lisp-program` to be `(shell-quote-argument "D:/Program Files/ccl/wx86cl.exe")`.

But when I run inferior lisp with the command `run-lisp`, emacs responds:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory, "D:/Program
```

It seemed that emacs treats `"D:/Program Files/ccl/wx86cl.exe"` as two arguments `"D:/Program` and `Files/ccl/wx86cl.exe"` separated by a space character.

How can I make emacs treat `"D:/Program Files/ccl/wx86cl.exe"` as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the old `"Progra~1"` compatibility name for `"Program Files"`.  So,

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "D:/Progra~1/ccl/wx86cl.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, scvalex. Your `"Progra~1"` method works quite well. But the other two don't work on my computer. Emacs responds: `Spawning child process: invalid argument`. Do you know why?

Comment: @wyqtl The last method probably only works as a shell escape in the command prompt.  Removed it.  I'm not sure why the first one doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, @wvxvw . It's really a great alternative method.

Comment: @scvalex The `(setq inferior-lisp-program "D:/Program Files/ccl/wx86cl.exe")` probably won't work. I looked at the source code of emacs's `run-lisp` function. There's a line saying that `(split-string cmd)`. So emacs deliberately splits the string. And the .emacs files you sited also used a path without spaces. Could you please edit your answer and then I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Done.  Hah; so there are at least two incorrect .emacs files on the web.

Comment: @wyqtl Also, great job on eliminating the incorrect solutions; most people would have just stopped after they found one that works.